# Indexing into array with functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to modify the example of kernel density estimation from https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/tree/master/examples/kde to only have one 1 line instead of 2. To do that I need to modify the code below. More specifically, I need to modify `.data(d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth))`. From Chrome Developer Tools I can see that the variable returned from `var bw = d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth)` is the following:

```
bw: Array[2]
0: function (x) {
1: function (x) {
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I've tried indexing into this variable, but the returned function cannot be used for plotting. It becomes `undefined`.

```
var granularity = 0.1;
var x_min = 30;
var x_max = 110;

d3.json("faithful.json", function(faithful) {
  data = faithful;
  var w = 800,
      h = 400,
      x = d3.scale.linear().domain([30, 110]).range([0, w]);
      bins = d3.layout.histogram().frequency(false).bins(x.ticks(60))(data),
      max = d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.y; }),
      y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .1]).range([0, h]),
      kde = science.stats.kde().sample(data);

  var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

   var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
      .data(bins)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + (h - y(d.y)) + ")";
      });

  bars.append("rect")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.dx + 30) - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); });

  var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .y(function(d) { return h - y(d[1]); });

  var bw = d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth);

  vis.selectAll("path")
      /* .data(d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth)) */
      .data(bw[1])
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", function(h) {
        return line(kde.bandwidth(h)(d3.range(x_min, x_max, granularity)));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data()` expects an [array](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data).  Use:

```
.data([bw[1]])
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0kFIX3lp0qgwuZlMz6Ma?p=preview).